# SQL DISTINCT JOIN OR WORKAROUND TO RETURN SINGLE RESULT

Tags: sql-server

I was looking but I don't see this exact issue with `Distinct`.

**SETUP**
4 tables

```
Users (UserId, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone)
CuUsers (UserId, AccountId, PrimaryUser)
HrUsers (UserId, EmployeeId, DeptId)
VendUser (UserId, VendorId...)
```

**PURPOSE OF DESIGN**
A user may be any or multiple of these Employee, Customer, Vendor
A User may be an Owner of a Customer Account, or multiple Accounts
A User May be an owner in one account, and employee of another account

**THIS QUERY**
Is trying to get a list of Customer Users Only

**DESIRED RESULT**
I want an Alphabetical List of `LastName` so that I can use it as a button filter So I only get a result of Alphabet where Users are customers i.e. So if noone's last name begins with Z I don't get a z to filter

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvSelectCustomerAlpha" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlSelectUserAlpha" 
         DataKeyNames="UserId" EnableModelValidation="True">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' runat="server" ID="btnAlpha"
              CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserId") %>' OnClick="btnSelectAnAccount_Click" 
              CssClass="small" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholderContainer" class="pager">                        
            <div class="clr"></div>
                <span class="title">Last Name:</span>
                <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></div>
            </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlSelectUserAlpha" 
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:MySolutionsCnSt %>' 
     SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(Users.LastName,1,1)) AS LastName, CuAcctsUsr.UserId FROM CuAcctsUsr LEFT OUTER JOIN Users ON CuAcctsUsr.UserId = Users.UserId" />
```

The sql command

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(Users.LastName,1,1)) AS LastName, 
       CuAcctsUsr.UserId FROM CuAcctsUsr LEFT OUTER JOIN Users ON 
       CuAcctsUsr.UserId = Users.UserId
```

My list returns 4 instances of L when I only need one, and I need the `userId` to get user Info from one table and check for Customer in the other, otherwise I have to duplicate all user info into both tables.

Is there a way to return only a single instance of each letter used in the `LastName` field if `UserId`'s are different? I apologize if this has been posted before, but I didn't see an exact work for this type of request
!(http://mycleaningsolution.com/desiredresult.jpg)

Comment: This is a badly written question. Please format the question in a more readable fashion, rather than a long paragraph without punctuation. Also, just include the SQL itself. What does all the rest of the XML text have to do with your question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: First Time User, didn't format like I wanted, sorry. I guess my question is simply WHY does Sql not just DISTINCT the one column I want and not the others, why does it apply distinct to all, and is there a workaround without having to duplicate tables columns and data?

Comment: DISTINCT applies to **all** the result columns. That's how SQL DISTINCT works.

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a keyword applied to the `SELECT` statement. Statement syntax is:

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] expr, expr, ... FROM table ...
```

Adding the `DISTINCT` keyword will ensure that duplicate rows are eliminated, hence result rows becoming "distinct". The **entire** row is compared.

For doing something like that on subset of columns, look at `GROUP BY`.

Your syntax looks confusing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(Users.LastName,1,1)) AS LastName,
       CuAcctsUsr.UserId

-- Same as above
SELECT  DISTINCT  (SUBSTRING(Users.LastName,1,1)) AS LastName,
                  CuAcctsUsr.UserId

-- Same as above
SELECT  DISTINCT  SUBSTRING(Users.LastName,1,1) AS LastName,
                  CuAcctsUsr.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select lastname , min(id) from 
(SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(name,1,1)) AS LastName, id from tbl1) as myusers
group by lastname
```

this code return just one userid for each letter